# When i run SHOW CREATE TABLE 'table_name' query it was showing create table script(Not Full Script) i want to see full script

Tags: mysql

**Output as follows in phpmyadmin**
How to view the full create table script

```
|  ---- Table ----  |  ----- Create Table ---     |
|  ---------------  |  -------------------------- |
|  table_name       |  CREATE TABLE `tbl_users` ( |
                        `userId`  int(11) NOT ... |
```

Comment: and what tool is that with?

Comment: I suspect the result is truncated in the result pane - can you drag it to full size?

Comment: ya i dragged it to full size but it wont show full script @P.Salmon

Comment: [image](http://i.imgur.com/LpqtAH0.jpg), came from [source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335469)

Answer (score 1):

click on **+ options** (present Above the result pane) in that select **full text** then click on **Go** you will get full script of your created table